# Unable to replicate the attributes of AD to SPO via AzureAD

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, user-profile-service, profile-sync, ad

I am trying to sync a custom property which is created in AD with SharePoint Online User Profiles.
I want to understand that while it is synced from AD to Azure AD, and while it is synced from Azure AD to the SPO directory, it is NOT replicated to the User Profile application.

Can anyone tell me the possible reason for the following?
Where am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default user profile synchronization in SharePoint Online synchronises only few standard set of properties.
**Custom AAD Properties are not synced to SharePoint online User profiles by default/OOTB synchronization mechanism**.You can see more details & the list of properties [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3168272/information-about-user-profile-synchronization-in-sharepoint-online).  Below is an excerpt from the link.

> Q4.Why isn't it possible to map additional properties for AD Import to
>   sync from Azure Active Directory to the User Profile Application?
>
> A4. AD Import is limited to a preconfigured set of properties to
>   guarantee consistent performance of the timer job.

You have to develop a custom user profile sync tool to sync your custom properties. You have two options to consider while developing the tool:

1. Use the API for Bulk Updating Custom User Profile Properties for SharePoint Online.
   See [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/Bulk-user-profile-update-api-for-sharepoint-online.md) for info
2. You can use the [Azure AD to User Profile Sync Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/bulk-user-profile-update-api-for-sharepoint-online) developed by PnP team for this.

Comment: I am using a tool right now called AD Mapper but I want to know, why is it not possible. What is stopping the attribute to be displayed in the SP User Profiles? If I create a new managed property in SP User Profiles and map it with Azure AD, will it work?

Comment: Please update your question with more information regarding your tool- "AD Mapper", is it a 3rd party tool. Probably a link to the specs of the tool.

Comment: The developers in my company have developed the AD Mapper tool. 
But I want to know what are the steps shall we follow for OOB method? Can you please provide me link of a site, blog or any place where I can check the steps and perform the same without using a tool?

Comment: You can't. You do not control the mappings between Azure AD and the UPSA in SPO. This is why you must replicate the attributes directly from Azure AD/AD to the SPO UPSA using an external tool.

Comment: Don't mind, but are you sure? Like really really more than 100% sure? I have said the same but now I need a proof. I can show you comment, if you can allow me :P

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ee721049.aspx#MapUserProc
This is the process followed in the server, is the same not possible for o365?

Comment: The process mentioned in the link only applies to On premise SharePoint. For SharePoint online you need to either develop a tool using bulk import API or use the PnP solution. Contact your dev team with this information.

Comment: The money quote in Unnie's link above is the answer to Q4 "AD Import is limited to a preconfigured set of properties to guarantee consistent performance of the timer job."

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Great that you point it out